# querySelectorAll not working

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I have a requirement where I have to pickup the last `.div` within a container and apply some business logic to it. The selection of the last `.div` has to be dynamic because the user has the option to add/remove `.div` elements.

Initially I tried with `querySelectorAll` but it did not seem to work. So I decided to change it to `getElementsByClassName` and surprisingly it worked with the same logic. Can somebody please help me with the reason for why the `remove_div` doesn't work while the second one (`remove_div_2`) does?

Note: I am not looking for a fix/solution to the issue because I have already proceeded with the second option. I just want to know the reason why the option with `querySelectorAll` doesn't work.

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='div1' class='div'>This is Div 1</div>
    <div id='div2' class='div'>This is Div 2</div>
    <div id='div3' class='div'>This is Div 3</div>
</div>
<button type='button' id='append_div'>Append Div</button>
<button type='button' id='remove_div'>Remove Div</button>
<button type='button' id='remove_div_2'>Remove Div 2</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elementToStyle = document.querySelectorAll("#container .div");
    elementToStyle[elementToStyle.length - 1].classList.add('red');

    document.getElementById('append_div').onclick = function () {
       var divToInsert = document.createElement('div');
       divToInsert.id = 'new_div';
       divToInsert.className = 'div';
       divToInsert.innerHTML = 'This is an appended div';
       document.getElementById('container').appendChild(divToInsert);
       var elToStyle = document.querySelectorAll("#container .div");
       for (i = 0; i < elToStyle.length; i++)
           elToStyle[i].classList.remove('red');
           elToStyle[elToStyle.length - 1].classList.add('red');
       };

       document.getElementById('remove_div').onclick = function () {
           var elToStyle = document.querySelectorAll("#container .div");
           document.getElementById('container').removeChild(elToStyle[elToStyle.length - 1]);
           elToStyle[elToStyle.length - 1].classList.add('red');
       };

       document.getElementById('remove_div_2').onclick = function () {
           var elToStyle = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
           document.getElementById('container').removeChild(elToStyle[elToStyle.length - 1]);
           elToStyle[elToStyle.length - 1].classList.add('red');
       };
   }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is because `querySelectorAll` method returns a static list. Any changes made to the document after the `querySelectorAll` is used (like `removeChild` in this case) will not be reflected in the list of nodes returned. Hence `elToStyle[elToStyle.length - 1]` would still point to the node that was removed.

Whereas, `getElementsByClassName` on the other hand returns a live list of nodes. This implies that `elToStyle[elToStyle.length - 1]` would always point to the last `.div` irrespective of any changes were done to the document after the node list was prepared or not.

Below is the extract from the official documentation available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall)

> The NodeList object returned by the querySelectorAll() method must be
>   static, not live ([DOM-LEVEL-3-CORE], section 1.1.1). Subsequent
>   changes to the structure of the underlying document must not be
>   reflected in the NodeList object. This means that the object will
>   instead contain a list of matching Element nodes that were in the
>   document at the time the list was created.

**Note:** You can see this by doing a `console.log(elToStyle);` both before and after the `removeChild`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the last division element just do the following...

```
var id = 'container';
var d = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('div')
var lastDiv = d[d.length - 1];
```

..and then apply your `querySelector`.

Comment: I think the user wants the last element with `class='div'` because it is mentioned as `.div` in the question

Answer (score -3):

You can access all the elements using querySelectorAll() like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('?').forEach(function(element) {
   // Now you can apply your changes to each element 
});
```