# Manipulate HTML elements added dynamically with 'vanilla' javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm creating a JavaScript plug-in which needs a fairly large/complex HTML structure to be rendered on the web page, before being manipulated via JavaScript. I don't want to use jQuery at all in this.

I'd like to be able to bundle all of the required code in a single JS file, which can be loaded into a parent web page and it'll 'do its thing'.  I'd rather the parent page did not have to include any additional HTML/CSS in order to work - I want everything to come from the single JS resource.

Currently I have the large chunk of HTML in a JavaScript variable as a string:

```
var templateBirthday = '\
    <section class="pwag-clearfix pwag-birthday-groups">\
        <div class="pwag-clearfix pwag-birthday-groups__inner">\
            <div class="pwag-birthday-group">\
                <p class="pwag-birthday-group__instruction">Enter the year of your birth</p>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--valid pwag-date-box--0">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value">1</span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--valid pwag-date-box--1">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value">9</span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--2">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--3">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="pwag-birthday-group">\
                <p class="pwag-birthday-group__instruction">Enter the month of your birth</p>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--4">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">M</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--5">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">M</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="pwag-birthday-group">\
                <p class="pwag-birthday-group__instruction">Enter the day of your birth</p>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--6">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">D</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--7">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">D</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="pwag-clearfix pwag-feedback">\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--year">The year you entered is invalid</span>\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--month">The month you entered is invalid</span>\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--day">The day you entered is invalid</span>\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--notLegal">You are not old enough to enter this site</span>\
        </div>\
    </section>\
';
```

I'm then rendering this into the parent page as follows:

```
function appendHtml(el, str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    while (div.children.length > 0) {
        el.appendChild(div.children[0]);
    }
}

appendHtml(document.body, templateBirthday);
```

It works fine; I see the HTML on the page.  However, now I need to be able to manipulate the various HTML elements from the same JS file.  So for example, I want do to this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.pwag-date-box')[0].style.border = '10px solid #f00';
```

However, because the HTML is being dynamically inserted it doesn't appear to be accessible by using the standard `document.querySelectorAll` type of methods in vanilla JS.

I fear my only option may be to create that massive chunk of HTML as 'proper' JavaScript objects rather than a string.  I was hoping there was a way to cheat and use a string for the HTML.

Does anyone know if it's possible to work with standard JS selectors on HTML which has been inserted into the DOM as a string?

Many thanks,

Dan

Comment: Sorry, that'd be my pseudo-code :)  I've modified the question so it should only return a single node to modify.

Comment: It depends on when you want to manipulate the html- on an event or after it has been insterted. It should work anyway just be sure to manipulate it after it has been inserted

Comment: I do advice on using getElementsByClassName if you are going to search on a classname. Otherwise as long as your editing the document after adding the html elements you should be fine. The reason for this is that getElementsByClassName returns a list of variables instead of a static list. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18735248/6270761

Comment: @sTx - I do believe this is an order-of-execution issue. Thanks for the nudge. Investigating...

Comment: @namlik What would be the advantage of a live node list in this case? The result of `document.querySelectorAll(...)` isn't stored in a variable for later use.

Comment: @Andreas Idd go for a live node list as he didnt specify there was going to be just change by javascript, if he later decides to add extra changes or implement functionality which depends on user behaviour he doesn't need te reinitialize the object. But if it is just for 1 operation straight afterwards he can absolutly use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: The script works ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddLdbrko/)) as long as you watch for the order of operations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple solution is using `document.getElementsByClassName()`. Hope it helps...

```js
var templateBirthday = '\
    <section class="pwag-clearfix pwag-birthday-groups">\
        <div class="pwag-clearfix pwag-birthday-groups__inner">\
            <div class="pwag-birthday-group">\
                <p class="pwag-birthday-group__instruction">Enter the year of your birth</p>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--valid pwag-date-box--0">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value">1</span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--valid pwag-date-box--1">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value">9</span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--2">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--3">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">Y</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="pwag-birthday-group">\
                <p class="pwag-birthday-group__instruction">Enter the month of your birth</p>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--4">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">M</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--5">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">M</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="pwag-birthday-group">\
                <p class="pwag-birthday-group__instruction">Enter the day of your birth</p>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--6">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">D</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="pwag-date-box pwag-date-box--7">\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__value"></span>\
                    <span class="pwag-date-box__placeholder">D</span>\
                    <input type="number" class="pwag-date-box__input" />\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="pwag-clearfix pwag-feedback">\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--year">The year you entered is invalid</span>\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--month">The month you entered is invalid</span>\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--day">The day you entered is invalid</span>\
            <span class="pwag-feedback__message pwag-feedback__message--notLegal">You are not old enough to enter this site</span>\
        </div>\
    </section>\
';

function appendHtml(el, str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    while (div.children.length > 0) {
        el.appendChild(div.children[0]);
    }
}

appendHtml(document.body, templateBirthday);

//using document.getElementsByClassName() instead of document.querySelectorAll()
document.getElementsByClassName('pwag-date-box')[0].style.border = '10px solid #f00'
```

```html
<body> </body>
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with `document.querySelectorAll`: https://jsfiddle.net/ddLdbrko/

Comment: Yeah. But, `querySelectorAll()` is used for complex queries. In this case, we can achieve it with `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Indeed - it was an order of execution issue. Thanks.

Comment: There is a simple and consistent interface for querying the DOM and I'm not allowed to use it for "simple" things? O.o Sorry but that's rubbish :) And this has still nothing to do with the problem of the TO

Comment: @Dan This shouldn't be the accepted answer - at least not with the given explanation.

Comment: I understood the answer to mean... "hey, here's a working example but I'm using `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead". As you rightly point out, `getElementsByClassName()` vs. `querySelectorAll()` is irrelevant, but the answer (and hopefully comments) demonstrate the issue was with the execution order not the detail of the selector.  Thanks all for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate the nodes *before* inserting them into the document tree.

```
let frag = new Range().createContextualFragment(str);
let newNodes = frag.querySelectorAll(".pwag-date-box")

// do modifications on newNodes here

el.appendChild(frag)
```